# How do i insert php geocoded address to the mysql database with a html form

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, geocoding

How do i insert php geocoded address to the mysql database i am having fileds like id,address,latitude, longitude and also i dont want to set the data hardcoded i want to send it through a html form but form should have only 1 textinput for address only and it should be stored on different fields in database like For ex: i enter address in input field it should be inserted to database address field and also the latitude and longitude should also be stored at the same time i search it for more than 2  days but  no result was found any help will be appreciated.

Comment: After 2 days, you couldn't find _any_ starting point at all?  You should be able to (and are expected to) put together some sort of attempt before asking a question here.

Comment: Please also note that the use case can be a potential breach to the Terms of Service of Google Maps Platforms, kindly see the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/#3-license) to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

While this question is very... ambitious on what you're going to get as an answer... I'll list out a couple of resources to help you get started...

Please refer to W3Schools on how to get started on form handling
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Please refer to MySQLi to get started on creating a connection and executing the "insert" statement to your MySQL database
https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Edit: Apparently links are not a proper answer... so here's a [proper] [edit2: but not accurate to the question] answer...

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0){
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
$stmt = mysqli_prepare( $link, "INSERT INTO Location(Address, Latitude, Longitude) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");\
$stmt->bind_param("sdd", $_POST['Address'], $_POST['Latitude'], $_POST['Longitude']);
$stmt->execute();
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action='#' method='POST'>
<input name='Address' type='text' />
<input name='Latitude' type='text' />
<input name='Longitude' type='text' />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit 2: Here's with Geocoding from Google (Which you need to have a Google Api Key which can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/?apis=maps)

```
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0){
  //Initate Curl
  $ch = curl_init();
  //GeoCoding Address
  $Google_API_KEY = "*****************";
  $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key={$Google_API_KEY}&address=" . urlencode($_POST['Address']) . "&sensor=false";
  //Handle the Curl Params
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  //Execute Curl and Decode JSON
  $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
  //var_dump($response);
  $geometry = $response['results'][0]['geometry'];
  $longitude = $geometry['location']['lat'];
  $latitude = $geometry['location']['lng'];
  $link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
  $stmt = mysqli_prepare( $link, "INSERT INTO Location(Address, Latitude, Longitude) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
  $stmt->bind_param("sdd", $_POST['Address'], $latitude, $longitude );
  $stmt->execute();
  }
  ?>
  <html>
  <body>
  <form action='tester.php' method='POST'>
  <input name='Address' type='text' />
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

<strike>Please excuse the simplification</strike>

Edit 3: I'm not sure why this is "too broad". However, I would say this question is missing any attempt on what they are tried... however if they indeed did try doing it for two days then let's just decode what the user said...

(1) How do i insert php geocoded address to the mysql database

- In my code I showed how to insert a geocoded address to the mysql database

(2) i am having fields like id,address,latitude, longitude

- Just a note on what fields are necessary

(3) also i dont want to set the data hardcoded i want to send it through a html form but form should have only 1 textinput for address only

- A note on what the flow should be and the requirement of 1 text input in the html

(4) and it should be stored on different fields in database like For ex: i enter address in input field it should be inserted to database address field and also the latitude and longitude

- In my code, it does indeed look up the address and then enter the latitude and longitude into the database

(5) should also be stored at the same time i search it

- In my code it does

(6) for more than 2 days but no result was found any help will be appreciated.

- A plea for help. Don't worry, I got you <3

And as this is considered the best place to go on the internet for coding help, I figured hell, why not help a [new] user out. In any case, I believe I indeed did answer the [disambiguate] question the user asked

Comment: A list of links is not an answer

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  OP says the form only collects address, not longitude and latitude.  Honestly, this should just be deleted, as OP's "question" doesn't contain nearly enough information to provide a quality answer.

Comment: The OP is new... I'll rewrite my answer to include geocoding... give me a minute

Comment: You should not attempt to answer questions that are this broad.

Comment: Please see my edit. If you really think I shouldn't be answering this question... maybe I'll bite the cost of a down-vote to help a new user out.

Comment: We don't care whether OP is new or not. A question with that many down-votes and close-votes should be enough for you to know you shouldn't answer it.